What would be the punishment for a pedophilic act/statutory rape according to halacha?
Would it necessitate capital punishment, public humiliation like flogging, or something less severe? Sources please.

There is no standalone commandment against non penetrative pedophilia but it could be a damage.
Bava Kamma lists the categories of damage that could occur.
Nézek: Damage or tort
Tsa'ár: Pain or suffering
Shavát: Stoppage of work
Ripui: Cost of cure
Bṓšeṯ: Shame or disgrace
If there was no physical or mental injury and all parties lived in a paedo society where to be molested wasn't considered disgraceful, there would be no damages.
However, the Rabbis (or the King) have a secular authority to flog, execute people, and impose fines even when there aren't kosher witnesses or the act isn't a formal sin.
But is any particular action necessitated? There is a commandment not to stand idly when your neighbor's blood is being spilled so it would make sense that executing, imprisoning, banishing etc. the pedophile would be an obligation and I'm sure some rabbis will rule that way, but I don't think it's explicitly codified in the Mishna Brura or Shulchan Aruch.
see below regarding this authority:
https://jcpa.org/article/horaat-shaah-the-emergency-principle-in-jewish-law-and-a-contemporary-application/

Is there a halachic punishment for intercourse with a minor/statutory rape?

The halachic punishment is Monetary and fairly limited (though the rabbis could impose a non halachic penalty)
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960634/jewish/Naarah-Betulah-Chapter-One.htm

I don't know that it's so "limited".  Boshes and tzaar are based on how much the victim would pay to not have gone through that, which I'd imagine would be very high, at least in current society.  My understanding is that therapy (under ripuy) can also be expensive (though that would probably go to the insurance company, not the victim).

See section 8 of the Mishneh Torah link in my previous comment. The kenas requires vaginal sex and (kosher) witness. If boshes is limited to how much the woman would pay not to be raped, it's effectively capped at what she owns. One can effectively rape a poor girl cheaply. There would also have to be kosher witness to extract the money from the man.  The halachic avenue is indeed limited.

Note if the act was homosexual or (in most cases) involving a female who has once menstruated, then there is certainly a formal prohibition. I know that's not every case but it's at least a fair amount of them.
